# Raspberry Pi WiFi Hotspot / Access Point

Tags: pi-3, wifi, pi-4, access-point, hotspot

I am a beginner Raspberry Pi user and my knowledge is mainly around software.

I don't know the correct terms for what I am trying to do so this may be a duplicate question.

Is it possible to connect to a Raspberry Pi via WiFi from another device and be on the 'same network' so I can ssh into it and view a site running locally on the Pi.

So for example if the Pi is running a site on localhost with nginx.

I want to connect to the Pi and visit the ip of the Pi (192.168.0.x) and view the site running on the Pi.

Similarly, I'd like to ssh in to the Pi.

I'm not sure the name of what I am trying to do or if its possible.

--

Also, not sure if it's also possible to have the Raspberry Pi connected to another network for internet via Ethernet or WiFi.

Comment: It is certainly possible to connect different interfaces to different networks, but I have no idea what you are actually trying to do. Post details and diagnostics and don't try to hide private IP Addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand what you mean with:

> to connect to a Raspberry Pi via WiFi from another device and be on the 'same network'

This implies a comparison. Same to what? You can create an access point on the RasPi to which you can connect like any other hotspot. This access point defines a subnet. This subnet can be part of your home network. On the RasPi you can install **nginx** and you can access its web interface as usual with web addresses. If you connect the RasPi to your home network with an ethernet cable then **nginx** is available on your home network too and not only for the devices connected to the access point by WiFi.

You can find a configuration example at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). If you want to connect the access point to your home network, then you need a bridge. Have a look at section **Setting up an access point with a bridge** for this.

Comment: Sorry, a way I can explain what I am trying to do is similar to those WiFi cameras you can buy off eBay, where you turn it on and it creates a WiFi network, then you join the WiFi network using your phone and then can view the camera. That but with a Pi as the camera and I wanted to connect to it's WiFi with my phone/laptop. - I don't know what this is called so I can't say what I want : /

Comment: @HH Exactly that is what I explained in the answer. Setup an access point as shown in the linked guide.